# Curl request from public ip address in php

Tags: php, curl

I am submitting curl request. But, when I used `$info = curl_getinfo($ch);`
It's showing me below data:

```
Array(
[url] => example.com
[content_type] => text/html
[http_code] => 403
[header_size] => 160
[request_size] => 510
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.046355
[namelookup_time] => 0.004173
[connect_time] => 0.024421
[pretransfer_time] => 0.02476
[size_upload] => 303
[size_download] => 1233
[speed_download] => 26599
[speed_upload] => 6536
[download_content_length] => 1233
[upload_content_length] => 303
[starttransfer_time] => 0.046307
[redirect_time] => 0
[redirect_url] => 
[primary_ip] => xx.xx.xx.xx
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_port] => 80
[local_ip] => 100.76.226.11
[local_port] => 39221
)
```

Here, local IP address is internal IP (100.76.226.11) not the public IP of the server. And server is refusing connection because it has whitelisted public IP. How to send curl request using public IP from the client side?

Comment: That depends on your exact network conditions. Is there some proxy/NAT involved? Or different network interfaces? Or is the target server on the same network?

Comment: @deceze: no. just one single server. target server is on different network

Comment: So what's the difference between the internal and public IP exactly?

Comment: @deceze: So, When post curl request, third party server is not recognized my public IP. And because of firewall from their side request is blocking. That's why I ran `get_info` in curl to know which IP address is being used and I saw its internal.

Comment: Yeah, that much is clear. The question is, where does your server get its "public" and "internal" IP from? Are those two different network interfaces? Is there a local LAN IP and a public facing proxied IP?

Comment: Server is on windows azure platform. I can see public and intenal IPs over there. I don't know much about networking. I just launched a server on azure.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to set the `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` option.

For more info see the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) which is where I got the following snippet from.

> CURLOPT_INTERFACE: The name of the outgoing network interface to use. This can be an interface name, an IP address or a host name.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "YOUR PRIMARY IP");
```

Comment: Getting this error: `URL Error #:bind failed with errno 99: Cannot assign requested address`

Comment: That means that the IP is not on an available interface. It is already in use or not even an IP on your machine.

Comment: When I use `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` to see server IP. its showing internal IP not the public. Why is that so?

Comment: Sounds like a question for Azure customer support. I'm not a sysadmin :(